# Loading Image sequence in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, image, performance, loading

I have to load image sequence animation about 60 images array. I want this particular sequence loaded separately. means that images loading time does not affected to whole page load time. because it is taking too much time to load page with image sequence animation. Currently i have added all 60 images of sequence in HTML code and set "display:none" to load with page.

Is there any possibility to load this images separately or load after my whole html page loaded. or any other better solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Load them dynamically using javascript/jquery

```
var imagePaths = ["img1.png", ....];
$(document).ready(function(){
   for(var i=0; i<imagePaths.length; i++) {
      var newImg = $('<img style="display:none;" />'); //Add any class or attribute you want or anything for images.
      newImg.bind("load", function(){
         $(this).show();
      });
      newImg.attr("src", imagePaths[i]);
      $(parentSelector).append(newImg);
   }
});
```

When you load dynamically from script, your HTML page would have loaded and be ready for use. And later all the images will come into view gradually.

**Edit:**
In addition if you want to keep your image hidden until it gets completely loaded, you could initially set `display:none;` inline and attach an onload listener, `display:block` there.

Hope this helps. Let me know if I missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

```
var images[60];
var names[60]={"img1.jpg","img2.jpg"...}

function loadImages() {
  for(var i=0;i<60;i++) {
    images[i] = new Image();
    images[i].src = "www.myWebPage.com/"+names[i];
  }
}
```

This function will now load images. Just make sure to call it after your page loads.

```
<body onLoad="loadImages()">
...
</body>
```